# How do you update upstream with changes from fork?

Tags: git, github

I have a main repository **A**, that I forked to repository **B**.  I've made some changes in **B** that I want to move up to **A**. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

First, what are the git commands to do this?

Second, can I do a pull request in github to facilitate this? How would that work?

Finally, I actually had a branch in B that I wanted to merge. Should I merge the branch in B back into my master branch before doing merge/pull request back to upstream repository (A)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways of doing this

1. Merge client side and interact with multiple remotes
2. Merge server side with Pull Requests, and only interact with 1 remote

Before you read on I'd just like to say that your question is relatively open-ended and there is not a single best answer to it. The following answer just reflect some of the workflows I've used to give you some insight.

#### Client Side

Supposing you are working on a clone of B, you can add A as a second remote:

```
git remote add repo_a <repo A URL>
```

`repo_a` is an alias for your remote repository, just as `origin` is likely your currrent alias for remote B. Let's rename `origin` to `repo_b` for the sake of clarity:

```
git remote rename origin repo_b
```

List your remotes:

```
git remote -v
```

Fetch stuff from both remotes

```
git fetch repo_a
git fetch repo_b
```

At this point, you can create local branches to track branches from both remote repositories without any restrictions on which way to merge, or what to merge. How you define your workflow will add certain constraints.

If, say, you'd like to merge changes from Repo B's `feature_1` branch into `repo_a`'s `master` branch, you could do:

```
git checkout -b master_a repo_a/master --track
git merge feature_1
git push repo_a master_a:master
```

You're biggest friend is `gitk` or any other graphical tool that will display local branches and remote branches in the same view. I suggest opening a detached `gitk` and refreshing it as often as you need. Don't forget the `--all` option.

```
gitk --all &
```

#### Server Side (Pull Requests)

In this next example, the client-side commands take place in a local clone of the `repo_b`. We will push features to `repo_b` on GitHub and use pull requests to merge.

When I work with pull requests I like to have `repo_b`'s master branch always in sync with the parent repository and it's common to use `upstream` and `origin` in `repo_b`'s client side clone:

```
git remote add upstream <repo A URL>
```

Reset your master branch to the `upstream`:

```
git fetch upstream
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master
git checkout -b feature_2
```

Implement your feature and push to Github:

```
git push origin feature_2
```

Now in the web interface you should have the option to submit a pull request when viewing that branch. I won't go through the details but it should be intuitive enough. Select `repo_b/feature_2` as source and `repo_a/master` as destination.

When the merge is done, you can update your `master` branch in your clone of `repo_b`:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure characterizing my question as being open ended is quite accurate. Since I had no idea how to even approach the problem, I had no idea there was more than one way to do it. It just turns out that there are several possibilities, which you have excellently provided a couple. More importantly is the insight into the problem that they provide. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, didn't mean "open-ended" negatively in any way. I just wanted to make it clear that there could be other valid answers. Your comment shows you've realized that already. Have fun with git!